# GoogleFit unknown activityId with hourly intervals

Tags: android, google-fit

Using Google Fit (`com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:20.0.0`), we're trying to cut activities at hourly intervals, but when we have an activity that straddles the hour, the `activityId` parameter in the first hours is 4 (unknown).

For example, imagining to have a 50 minutes of running (activity) from 10:40 to 11:30, we ask Google Fit about hourly intervals, specifically:

1. between 10:00 and 11:00 we expect 20 minutes of running, but instead of having 20 minutes results, we get a full range of 60 minutes of an unknown activity (that covers all minutes from 10:00 to 11:00), the outcome that come back to us is `activityId` 4;
2. between 11:00 and 12:00 we expect to receive 30 minutes of running and in this case they arrive correctly;

If we try to use a wider range that includes all the ongoing activity (for example from 10:00 to 12:00) the answer is correct and we get 50 minutes of running as expected.

We are using this aggregates:

```
.aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
.aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
.aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
.aggregate(DATASOURCE_ESTIMATED_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
```

with 1 minutes of `bucketByActivitySegment`.

This is the API that we invoke to read the data from Google Fit: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient

Any idea?